# Listen to multiple routers

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an Application with submodules and subrouting.
I need to install a service that reacts to every router change.

My problem is that i can't find a way to initialize it.
The Angular Module has no NgOnInit where i could pass a router object, the RouterModule doesn't have that either.

Unless i pass the router to my service in every Component, i do not see how to solve this.

Another ideas was to use the guards to set the router, but that seems dirty since that is not what guards are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you inject the router in the main component (usually in the app.component.ts) and then subscribe to its events?

```
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private router: Router) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.router.events.subscribe( event => {
        //here you will have an event, such as NavigatiunStart, NavigationEnd, etc...
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: the same thinking :) https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events#routing-events

Comment: I'd have to do it in every main component of every module. But it should work yes. I was hoping to do it in config thou. If no better answer comes up, this will be my solution i guess :-(

Comment: No @AndreschSerj you won't need to do this in every component. 'this.router.events' is an onservable, it will 'observe' each router change (the router changes emits a stream of events).

Comment: No, not in every component but in every main component, so once per module and with the amount of modules i have this still is not the ideal solution i was hoping for. But probably still the only one :-(
Thank you for your time and help thou

Answer (score 0):

Have one route service `RouteService` which listens to the route changes and acts accordingly.
Inject this `RouteService` in `app.component.ts`. 
Don't forget to provide the service in `app.module.ts`.

Since there will be single instance of this service. you can use it to hook into the route change

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteService {
constructor(public router: Router) {
    // this.initialize();  // You can initialize from here or from app component
}

initialize() {
    this.router.events.filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe((event: any) => {
        this.onRouteChange(event);
    });
}
onRouteChange() {
   // Handle route change.
}
}
```

Inject in `app.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(
       public routeService: RouteService) {
   }
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routeService.initialize(); // Intitialize here.
  }
}
```

Comment: As i said in my question, this is what i do not want to doi because i'd have to add this service to every component. That is too much code duplication, hard to maintain and ugly.

Comment: You wouldn't have to inject this in every component. As long as it has been injected in the app.component, it will be initialized (via initialize()) as soon as the app is loaded and then the subscription will handle each router change.

Comment: @andresch-serj. As @ChristianBenseler said,  You just have to inject this service once in the `app.component.ts` and handle the route there.

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani has the same solution as mine, with the simple difference that he has moved the logic to a service that will be injected (and then if you want to reuse it, will be simpler). But the idea is the same: subscribe to router events in the main component, and the events stream that will be emited by the router will be "listened" by the subscriber.